# Как пробросить данные из $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] в шаблон компонента мимо кэша?

Tags: битрикс

Задача:
Необходимо в шаблоне catalog.section парсить переменную `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` на наличие нужной utm метки, если она есть, модифицировать компонент (заменить один элемент в массиве).

Мои действия:
в `result_modifier.php` читаю `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, если есть метка удаляю один элемент ставлю другой. Все работает пока не включишь кэш. с включенным кэшем насколько я знаю `result_modifier` не обрабатывается, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` даже не распечатывается. 
композитный кэш не используется.

Подскажите как пробросить данные из `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` в шаблон компонента?

Задача решена в `component_epilog.php` + js но хотелось бы сделать на php

Comment: А что вам мешает парсить переменную прямо в шаблоне? Он же тоже php. Это несколько нарушает логику отделения бизнес-логики от шаблонов, но в ситуации с производительностью (которую решает кэширование) приходится идти на компромиссы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если component_epilog.php , то можно юзать отложенные функции. Типа буфер и всё такое.

Но я бы всё же рекомендовал обработать $_SERVER просто перед вызовом компонента и нужный результат передавать в параметрах. Так как компоненты кешируются под параметры => что под каждые настройки компонента, у вас будет свой кеш.